# Как получить значение масштабирование экрана конкретного устройства?

Tags: javascript, экран, scale

Мне требуется получать параметры экрана, с `width` и `height` проблем не возникает:

```
window.screen.width
window.screen.height
```

Можно ли получить масштабирование, которое задается в настройках винды для данного монитора?

Comment: `window.devicePixelRatio`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Что бы получить "плотность" пикселей для конкретного устройства можно воспользоваться методом интерфейса [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window), под названием [devicePixelRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio):

```js
const ratio = window.devicePixelRatio

console.log(ratio)
```

Если же Вы говорите о zoom-level'e, то он будет меняться в зависимости от пользовательских настроек в каждом конкретно браузере, и насколько мне известно универсального кросс-браузерного решения для его определения все еще нет.

Экспериментальный вариант:

```js
const scale = window.visualViewport.scale

console.log(scale)
// пока здесь не работае
```

пока [поддержка](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_visualviewport) данного [метода](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VisualViewport) не очень большая.